# Jaspersoft Studio: how to set the legend title?

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart, jaspersoft-studio

I'm using Jaspersoft Studio 6.6.0 Eclipse plugin and jasperreports library. For a bar chart, I'd like to set a title for the legend. How can I do it?

According to [Jaspersoft Wiki](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/advanced-chart-formatting), there is an "advanced" property "legend.title.text". It suggests I should enter it manually in "Advanced" tab, but in Jaspersoft Studio 6.6.0 Eclipse plugin there is no such thing as free-text property field, just a bunch of pre-defined properties. Am I blind? Or is this feature reserved for paid products?

Comment: Hi @badbishop, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem does not seem to be realted with Highcharts, but with `jaspersoft-studio`. To set legend title in Highcharts set `legend.title.text`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/waqk6xmu/

Comment: @ppotaczek: it was someone else who added highcharts tag, not me. I confirm that my question is related to Jaspersoft Studio. Actually, to JasperReports library (I don't mind editing text files manually, if it solves the problem).

Answer (score 1):

JasperReports (and Jaspersoft Studio Community Edition) charts are based on [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).  The wiki article talks about JasperReports Server Professional, which is a different product that features Ad Hoc charts based on [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/).

With JasperReports charts there's no built in feature to specify a title for the legend.

However, you can implement that on your own as a chart customizer (or chart theme, but that's a little more complicated).  The chart customizer would read a chart element property and use the JFreeChart to create a title for the legend.  It would look something like this:

```
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.block.BlockContainer;
import org.jfree.chart.block.LabelBlock;
import org.jfree.chart.title.LegendTitle;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleEdge;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChart;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChartCustomizer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesMap;

public class LegendTitleCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
        JRPropertiesMap elementProperties = jasperChart.getPropertiesMap();
        String legendTitleText = elementProperties.getProperty("legend.title.text");
        if (legendTitleText != null) {
            LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
            BlockContainer legendItems = legend.getItemContainer();
            BlockContainer legendWrapper = new BlockContainer();
            LabelBlock label = new LabelBlock(legendTitleText);
            legendWrapper.add(label, RectangleEdge.TOP);
            legendWrapper.add(legendItems, RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
            legend.setWrapper(legendWrapper);
        }       
    }
}
```

The chart element in the report would need to specify the chart customizer class and the property value:

```
<barChart>
    <chart customizerClass="LegendTitleCustomizer">
        <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="270" height="175">
            <propertyExpression name="legend.title.text">"Series"</propertyExpression>
        </reportElement>
        ...
```